# TableViewCells change on scroll Rxwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

my tableview cell change on scrolling down. I use rxswift to bind the tableview with the observables. How I can insure that the cells have the real values and dont change while scrolling ?

Here is my code:
let observableItems = viewModel.getShoppingList().asObservable()

```
    observableItems.bind(to: tableViewShoppingList.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "shoppingListCell", cellType: ShoppingListTableViewCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
        print(row)
        cell.nameTextField.text = element.title


        cell.amountLabel.isHidden = true

        //Check if Amount is nil
        if element.amount == "" {
            cell.amountTextField.placeholder == "Menge"
        } else {
            cell.amountTextField.text = element.amount
        }

        //Amount TextField
        cell.amountTextField
                       .rx
                       .controlEvent([.editingDidEnd])
                       .withLatestFrom(cell.amountTextField.rx.text)
                       .subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] (text) in
                           if text == "" {
                               //DO NOTHING
                           } else {
                               guard let text = text else { return }
                               let data = ShoppingListData(_id: element.id, title: element.title, amount: text, status: element.status, position: element.position)
                               self?.viewModel.updateShoppingListItem(data: data)
                           }
                       })
                           .addDisposableTo(cell.bag)

        //Check Status
        if element.status == true {
            cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected = false
        }

        //Checkmarc Button
        cell.checkMarcButton.rx.tap.asDriver()
            .drive(onNext: { [weak self] in
                if cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected {
                    cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected = false
                    let data = ShoppingListData(_id: element.id, title: element.title, amount: element.amount, status: false, position: element.position)
                    self?.viewModel.updateShoppingListItem(data: data)
                } else {
                    cell.checkMarcButton.isSelected = true
                    let data = ShoppingListData(_id: element.id, title: element.title, amount: element.amount, status: true, position: element.position)
                    self?.viewModel.updateShoppingListItem(data: data)
                }
            }).disposed(by: cell.bag)


    //TableView Style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue happens with your `cell.bag`, because the `UITableViewCell` is reusable, so the code of this part will be implemented many times

```
//Amount TextField
        cell.amountTextField
                       .rx
                       .controlEvent([.editingDidEnd])
                       .withLatestFrom(cell.amountTextField.rx.text)
                       .subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] (text) in
                           if text == "" {
                               //DO NOTHING
                           } else {
                               guard let text = text else { return }
                               let data = ShoppingListData(_id: element.id, title: element.title, amount: text, status: element.status, position: element.position)
                               self?.viewModel.updateShoppingListItem(data: data)
                           }
                       })
                           .addDisposableTo(cell.bag)
```

In this case, you should let your `cell.bag` to be var, and reinitiate bag every time you set the value.

I suggest you add one line in the closure

```
cell.bag = DisposeBag()
```

and it will be fine.